# Listview dropdownlist databinding in editmode without sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am Uday Satardekar,

In my [nridubai.com](http://nridubai.com) website,i am editing Event Information using EditTemplate in Listview.

And i want country to be edited from selected country.**And I am not using sqlDataSource.**

I am populating list of countries from code behind page.For this purpose i have used **OnItemDataBound** event. and this shows all countries in dropdownlist in edit mode.

Upto this working fine for me.

when i open lisview in editmode textbox for event name shows eventname from databse.

Like this when first time  dropdownlist for countries is loaded in edit  mode,it must show country belongs to event. like TextBox control.

I try like this

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="lstEditCountry" runat="server" 

                         selectedValue='<%# Eval("country_name") %>'
                              Width="174" />
```

but it thows exception .

Please help me. with example..................

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to bind `lstEditCountry` to a datasource when the row is in edit mode. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.editindex.aspx)

```
protected void List_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

  //Verify there is an item being edited.
  if (List.EditIndex >= 0)
  {

    //Get the item object.
    ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

    // Check for an item in edit mode.
    if (dataItem.DisplayIndex == List.EditIndex)
    {

      // Preselect the DropDownList control with the Title value
      // for the current item.

      // Retrieve the underlying data item. In this example
      // the underlying data item is a DataRowView object.        
      DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)dataItem.DataItem;

      // Retrieve the Title value for the current item. 
      String title = rowView["Title"].ToString();

      // Retrieve the DropDownList control from the current row. 
      DropDownList list = (DropDownList)dataItem.FindControl("lstEditCountry");

      //********populate the ddl here***********

      // Find the ListItem object in the DropDownList control with the 
      // title value and select the item.
      ListItem item = list.Items.FindByText(title);
      list.SelectedIndex = list.Items.IndexOf(item);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Regarding 
 

You have to bind "lstEditCountry" to a datasource when the row is in edit mode. For this which event is necessary? Means On which event i have to bind listEditCountry dropdownlist.

Comment: I updated the code.  You already have an ItemDataBound event, so you can just add it there.

Comment: Thanks...for above help. from last 2 days i am confused with this problem..  Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss